# Open external links in frames, like About.com?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to open pages in frames exactly how About.com does it. (For example go to http://netforbeginners.about.com/od/antivirusantispyware/a/malware101_2.htm and click on an external link like Cexx.org)

It looks like there is some kind of script running that makes any external link open in that way.

How can I implement the same?

Comment: View their source code if you need a tutorial

Answer (score 0):

What happens is that a new page is opened on about.com consisting of the html in the top and an iframe in which the link is opened. You can do this using basic JavaScript code.